# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning issue with strings and lambdas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, lambda

When performing the following piece of code,  I get this error:

**input**

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace('/', '')))
```

**output**

```
/..somepath.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:601: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
self.obj[item_labels[indexer[info_axis]]] = value
```

There are a few similar questions on the subject, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) one, however none of them include more complex issues such as column string manipulation through `lambda`. Also, in the answers there, once `.loc` is used, the issue seems to be fixed, whereas here it persists.

I went through the documentation and it seems that I need to use `.loc`, so I did (see code below), however my issues still persists.

```
df.loc[:,('col1')] = df.loc[:,('col1')].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace('/', '')))
```

Could you tell me if this is a different problem that I am having and how it can be fixed, so that I know better going forward?

**EDIT: previous code**

Below is the df initialization and a few extra lines of code before the like with the problem

```
d = df[df['col0'].str.contains('text')]
if not df.empty:
```

I generally tend to not use `.loc` for all `DataFrame` operations, as I find it less readable. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Protip: If your question is about pandas, add the pandas tag.

Comment: I missed it, by bad. Thanks!

Comment: I think problem is in code before your row. Can you show2-3 rows of code?

Comment: How did you initialise `df`?

Comment: updated the post now

Comment: Then need `d = df[df['col0'].str.contains('text')].copy()`

Comment: @jezrael this fixed it! Could you please explain what the issue was?

Comment: If you modify values in `d` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df`), and that Pandas does warning.